# how to make legend text as clickable in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

```html
var text=["level1","level2","level3"]
var color=['blue','black','green']

var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("id","ad")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(210,40)');
  
legend.selectAll('#ad')
  .data(text)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i){ return i *  100;})
  .attr("y", height)
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill",function(d,i){return color(i);});

legend.selectAll('text')
  .data(text)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d, i){ return i *  100 + 15;})
  .attr("y",height+10)
  .attr("class","leg_txt_font")
  .text(function(d,i){ return text[i];});
```

i have tried above code to set the legend.,how to make legend text as clickable in d3.js
i have to set legend text as clickable..if i click the legend text means just need to show the alert message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `on("click", function(){ ... })`:

```
selection.on("click", function(d){
    alert(d)
});
```

In the snippet bellow, click on the legend to get the alert:

```js
var text=["level1","level2","level3"];
var color=['blue','black','green'];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 400);

var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("id","ad")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(40,40)');
  
var rects = legend.selectAll('#ad')
  .data(text)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i){ return i *  100;})
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill",function(d,i){return color[i];});

var texts = legend.selectAll('text')
  .data(text)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d, i){ return i *  100 + 15;})
  .attr("y",60)
  .attr("class","leg_txt_font")
  .text(function(d,i){ return text[i];})

texts.on("click", function(d){
  alert(d)
});
```

```css
text {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you make it this answer runable at js fiddle?

Comment: The snippet is right here! Just click "run code snippet", you're gonna see three legends. Click on any of them, you're gonna see the alert.